# how to use estraverse js library on client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower, esprima

I was able to get estraverse via npm and get it work on a node app. But when when i tried to install it via bower for client side usage, the install failed saying "optionator package is not found". And when i tried to load the js file directly, it showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" in the console.

Comment: Do you happen to find the solution for the error"Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"? I face the same error too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Apparently the current estraverse code base is not working in a web browser but it works fine in browserify or webpack. Thus, you need to built estraverse using any of this module.

I used browserify to to built it using the code below:

```
browserify --standalone estraverse estraverse-master/estraverse.js > estraverse-master/build/estraverse.browser.js
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: *"is not working in a web browser but it works fine in browserify or webpack"* browserify and webpack are not JavaScript environments. They don't execute JavaScript code, so code cannot work "in" them. They are module bundlers which bundle modules into a single file so it can be executed in browsers.